# Grouping in R changes mean substantially

Tags: r, grouping

I have a file containing the predictions for two models (A and B) on a binary classification problem. Now I'd like to understand how good they are predicting the observations that they are most confident about. To do that I want to group their predictions into 10 groups based on how confident they are. Each of these groups should have an identical number of observations. However, when I do that the accuracy of the models change substantially! How can that be?

I've also tested with `n_groups=100`, but it only makes a minor difference. The CSV file is [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LprPRd) and the code is below:

```
# Grouping observations 
conf <- read.table(file="conf.csv", sep=',', header=T)
n_groups <- 10
conf$model_a_conf <- pmax(conf$model_a_pred_0, conf$model_a_pred_1)
conf$model_b_conf <- pmax(conf$model_b_pred_0, conf$model_b_pred_1)
conf$conf_group_model_a <- cut(conf$model_a_conf, n_groups, labels=FALSE, ordered_result=TRUE)
conf$conf_group_model_b <- cut(conf$model_b_conf, n_groups, labels=FALSE, ordered_result=TRUE)

# Test of original mean.
mean(conf$model_a_acc) # 0.78
mean(conf$model_b_acc) # 0.777

# Test for mean in aggregated data. They should be similar.
(acc_model_a <- mean(tapply(conf$model_a_acc, conf$conf_group_model_a, FUN=mean))) # 0.8491
(acc_model_b <- mean(tapply(conf$model_b_acc, conf$conf_group_model_b, FUN=mean))) # 0.7526
```

**Edited to clarify slightly.**

Comment: Maybe comparing `mean(1:10)` with `mean(c(mean(1:2),mean(3:10)))` would be helpful?

Comment: Could someone explain why the question has been down-voted and voted to be closed? I've been looking at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-or-on-hold-question, but cannot see a reason that fits. Is it too unclear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
table(conf$conf_group_model_a)
1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10 
2515 2628 2471 2128 1792 1321  980  627  398  140
```

The groups you are using are unbalanced. So when you take the mean of each of those groups with `tapply` thats fine, however to simply take the `mean` afterwards is not the way to go.

You need to weight the means by their size if you want to do the process you have.

something like this is quick and dirty:

```
mean(tapply(conf$model_a_acc, conf$conf_group_model_a, FUN=mean) * (table(conf$conf_group_model_a)/nrow(conf)) * 1000)
```

Comment: Ah, thanks! The cut function apparently divides by the value instead of splitting the observations. Do you know how to split the observations evenly into n groups based on the confidence?

Comment: @felbo `cut` doesn't do any division, it simply splits the observations into 10 groups just as you wanted. The problem is that you may not have a total number of observations that splits _evenly_ into 10 groups.

Comment: @joran I could have expressed myself more clearly. I meant that cut apparently "divides the value spectrum" into the 10 different groups and then organizes the observations based on that, whereas I want to simply organize the observations into 10 evenly sized groups based on their value. `N=15000` so it shouldn't be a problem to split the observations evenly ;)